# CDAP PUBSUB Realtime Pipleine MAP Datatype

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Im trying to pull through a pubsub subscription using cdap realtime pipeline.

I can connect the pubsub up but the attributes column is coming through as a MAP datatype and I seen unable to do anything with it (I need the data in it).

The idea is to take that message and place it in a database for further processing.

Is there any way to take the MAP data type and convert it to something useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the column using JavaScript transform plugin.

```
output.attributes = JSON.stringify(output.attributes);
```

This will convert the map type to a string.